# Nested do-while loop in if-else: variable not initialized

Tags: java, loops, initialization, syntax-error, nested-loops

I'm stuck with a error I repedeatly got in Eclipse. I think that this error shouldnt exist. Given ist the following nested loop:

```
String conditionlogic;
if(matcher.find())
{               
    do
        conditionogic += matcher.group();
    while(matcher.find());
}
else
    conditionogic = null;
```

The error is

> The local variable conditionlogic may not have been initialized.

It is my understanding, that since do-while will be executed at least once conditionlogic is actually initialized with one or more values of matcher.group() or else null.
How can I fix this?

Comment: use { } with do and while too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What does this line means:

```
conditionogic += matcher.group();
```

This is the same as:

```
conditionogic = conditionogic + matcher.group();
```

i.e. it means: take the value of `conditionogic` and concatenate to it `matcher.group()`. But value of `conditionogic` indeed is unknown when you enter the loop first time. You have to assign something to this variable, for example empty string:

```
String conditionlogic = "";
```

Comment: +1. I'd like to have a fairly robust conversation with the guys who allowed `+=` to be used on a string in Java. A kludge in a language that does not allow operator overloading; in my opinion.

Comment: @Bathsheba, be lenient to beginners. You cannot expect every person that starts learning java to use `StringBulder` or guava `Joiner` for string concatenation.

Comment: Thank you. I realized that shortly after -.-
Why shouldn't I use += on a String? What are the advantages of other methods mentioned?

Comment: `String` is immutable, i.e. its content is never changed. When you write `res = s1 + s2` you create additional instance of `String`. When you are doing this in loop number of additional objects is like number of your iterations. `StringBuilder` solves this problem by accumulating chunks and creating the final string when all concatenations are done.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `conditionogic += matcher.group();` (a `+=` operator), So you have to initialize your `conditionlogic` with empth String `""`, like this :

```
String conditionlogic = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your case is the `+=` operator. What do you `+=` on if the variable is not initialized?

You probably want to initialize the value to `""`.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your code carefully, you're trying to concatenate the result of `matcher.group()` to `null`. The error is perfectly valid, you should initialize conditionLogic to `""`.

However, this at the moment isn't really good practice, concatenating strings like that in a loop. The right way to do it is this:

```
String conditionLogic = null;
if(matcher.find())
{
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    do
    {
        sb.append(matcher.group());
    }
    while(matcher.find());
    conditionLogic = sb.toString();
}
```